# Maven cyclic dependency issue for Spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, cyclic-dependency

I have a Spring project which contains ~50 components. Unfortunately, one of the classes caused an issue of cyclic dependency in Maven. Here's the story:

I added a new component to my Spring project. Let's call it *`Apple`* for now. It has a `@Bean` called *`AppleWatch`*. One of the implementations was that *`Apple`* lived (depended) on another component: *`Foxconn`*, so that *`AppleWatch`* could call a method in a Bean called *`CheapLabor`*.

At the meantime, *`CheapLabor`* depended on another component: *`Corning`*. It needed *`GorillaGlass`* to be able to work overtime.

Things were pretty good until the moment *`Corning`* realizes that it wants to save money by making the similar amount of glasses according to the Apple's market need. So it tries to call a method *`getCurrentMarketOrders()`* in *`AppleWatch`*. To do so, I autowired the bean *`AppleWatch`* into the class *`GorillaGlass.java`*. Then...

Boom! Cyclic dependency error!

So, any suggestion on what should I do for *`Apple`* and/or *`Corning`*?

Comment: The usual advice would be to depend on interfaces rather than implementations--I suspect that would help here. Also, think about the direction of your dependencies..for example, I can see a watch depending on a glass crystal, but not the other way around. It kinda sounds like your GorillaGlass class somehow depends on AppleWatch--makes me scratch head, but maybe I just misunderstand the issue.

Comment: Is this a build time error or a runtime (including unit tests) error?

Comment: @unigeek I agree. Re-designing the structure of project accordinglysurely solves the problem. But it turned out that I couldn't change the structure without driving my boss/colleagues crazy. There are many approaches to solve cyclic dependency issues. I came up with this after all: moving the logic that `Corning` depends on `Apple` to be a part of `Apple`: instead of getting needed info from `Apple`, `Coring` now gets those information from `Foxconn`, which calls the method from `Apple`. It break the circle to `Apple` -> `Foxconn` -> `Corning`. Not the best move but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @unigeek, interfaces are your friends in this case. And in context of structuring your maven project this means separating interfaces into separate API maven modules.

Soon `Corning` will realize it also supplies `GorrilaGlass` to `Samsung`, not just `Apple`. So now it needs to call `getCurrentMarketOrders()` not only on `AppleWatch`, but also `Gear2`. The solution becomes more clear at this point: introduce an API module with `Marketable` interface that both `Apple` and `Samsung` depend on, allowing both `AppleWatch` and `Gear2` implement `Marketable`. Then `Corning` simply depends on this new API module, without having direct dependencies on either `Apple` or `Samsung`, while the latter both provide their own implementations to this interface.